# Problem when i configure permalink

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

When I changed the permalink to `/%postname%/` I lost the connection with server... and I need to clean .htaccess to access again... how can i fix it?

What do I need to put in .htaccess?

My current `.htaccess` is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What was the permalink setting before you changed it?

Answer (score 0):

The basic rewrite rules for pretty permalinks in WordPress look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Note the `RewriteRule`. That part is missing in your file.

Comment: Hello, i changed my .htaccess. and now i see this message: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Is mod_rewrite active at all?

Comment: I don't know. You'are talking about 'permissions' like 644, 755?

Comment: @FelipeStoker No, I’m talking about the Apache module. If you remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>`, do you get an error?

Comment: I discovered the problem:
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX.com.br [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.XXX.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?XXX.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2013/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2013/blog$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?XXX.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ 2013/blog [L]